# Am I doing something wrong in this recounting problem?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

4.These problems involve a jelly bean factory that makes 5 different colors of jelly beans: blue, orange, green, pink and purple. They randomly combine the jelly beans of different colors into bags to sell.

B. How many different bags of 10 jelly beans are possible if there are only 4 purple available?
(The factory is almost out of purple jelly beans.)

My solution:
[image: My solution]

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct, but here is an easier way.

The total number of options, ignoring the restriction on purples, is $C(14,4)$.

The number of options containing $5$ or more purple jelly beans is $C(9,4)$ since we have to choose $5$ jelly beans from $5$ colours.

The latter options are impossible and so the answer is
$$C(14,4)-C(9,4)=1001-126=875\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

Seems perfectly fine to me. To tidy up, one could wrap it up in a summation:

$$\sum_{x_5=0}^{4} {10 + 3 - x_5\choose{3}} $$