# Is the solution to these problems correct and are there straightforward ways about doing these problems?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> A jelly bean factory that makes 5 different colors of jelly beans: blue, orange, green, pink and purple. They randomly combine the jelly beans of different colors into bags to sell.
>
> How many different bags of 10 jelly beans are possible?

**My Answer**

By the stars and bars argument, the number of solutions is equal to the number of ways of permuting $10$ stars and $5-1=4$ bars,

$$\binom{10+5-1}{5-1}=\binom{14}{4}=\frac{14!}{10!4!}=1001$$

> How many different bags of 10 jelly beans are possible if there are only 4 purple and 4 orange available?

**My solution**

Here we must resort to polynomials.  The total number of ways is given by the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in

$$(1+x+x^2+\cdots)(1+x+x^2+\cdots)(1+x+x^2+\cdots)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)$$
$$=(1+x+x^2\cdots)^3(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^2$$

But $1+x+x^2+\cdots=\frac{1}{1-x}$ and $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4 = \frac{1-x^5}{1-x}$, so

$$(1+x+x^2\cdots)^3(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^2=\frac{(1-x^5)^2}{(1-x)^5}=(1-2x^5+x^10)(1-x)^{-5}$$

The coefficient of $x^{10}$ in the above expression is equal to
$k_{10}-2k_5+k_0$ in the expansion of $(1-x)^{-5}$, where $k_a$ is the coefficient of the $x^a$ term.

$$k_{10}=\binom{5+10-1}{5-1}=\binom{14}{4}=\frac{14!}{10!4!}=1001$$
$$k_{5}=\binom{5+5-1}{5-1}=\binom{9}{4}=\frac{9!}{5!4!}=126$$
$$k_{0}=\binom{5+0-1}{5-1}=\binom{4}{4}=\frac{4!}{0!4!}=1$$

Thus the total is $1001-2\cdot126+1=750$.

Comment: Absurdly similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2036605/329832

Comment: Yes because the me and my friends are getting different solutions and I just want to make sure that I am doing this correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use stars and bars: Subtract the number of bags with at least 5 orange or 5 purple from the unrestricted total  $\binom {14}{4}.$

The  number of bags with at least 5 purple is the number $A(5,5)$ of bags with just 5 beans without restrictions on the numbers of each bean,   because  you have $A(5,5)$ different bags of 5 beans, and you can add 5 purple to each of them. Similarly, with at least 5 orange, we have $A(5,5).$

If we add these, we have double-counted the number of bags that have at least 5 purple and 5 orange, which is just 1 bag.

By the stars-and-bars method, $A(5,5)=\binom {9}{4}.$

So the final answer is $$\binom {14}{4}- 2\binom {9}{4}+1=1001-2(126)+1=750.$$